# Python: Install TensorFlow Federated learning

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to install TensorFlow Federated Learning in Python 3.10.2
All the package installed successfully, but in the end I encountered the error

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
 × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\alnas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dl8ki6sq\absl-py_ad6a95823df04cca88af49f562773b85\setup.py", line 34, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError('Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.')
      RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
      [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Answer (score 0):

The setup.py script absl-py package is raising a RuntimeError because its requires python version 2.7 or 3.4+, and it seems version that is doesn't support. Kindly check the python version and update tensorflow federated learning also.

There are a few ways to set up your environment to use TensorFlow Federated (TFF):

The easiest way to learn and use TFF requires no installation; run the TensorFlow Federated tutorials directly in your browser using Google Colaboratory.

To use TensorFlow Federated on a local machine, install the TFF package with Python's pip package manager.

Kindly follow the below steps to install the Tensorflow Federated using pip and follow commands.

1. Install the Python development environment.

   ```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip  # Python 3
   ```
2. Create a Virtual Environment.

   ```
   python3 -m venv "venv"
   source "venv/bin/activate"
   pip install --upgrade "pip"
   ```
3. Install the released TensorFlow Federated Python package.

   ```
    pip install --upgrade tensorflow-federated
   ```
4. Test Tensorflow Federated

   ```
    python -c "import tensorflow_federated as tff; 
    print(tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello World')())"
   ```

Kindly find the Reference link for install the [Tensorflow Federated](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/install).